# Is it possible to handle the selected local notification when activing the app from iOS notification panel?

Tags: ios, notifications, center, local

When launching the app from a local notification you can use the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method of ApplicationDelegate to handle the notification, but this method is not called when you select the notification in the notifications panel and the app is in background.

Is there a way to handle the notification in that case?

I want to show a special viewcontroller when the app becomes active by this cause.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the below delegate method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Comment: Thanks! I suposssed this method it was called only when the notification was fired and not when the notification is selected in this panel. I think the documentation it is not enough clear in that point.